# Good way to down-dimension (extract) of a 3D tensor (or same as numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have some data stored in a certain 3D tensor

```
data1 = torch.ones(3, 3, 3, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)   
data2 = torch.zeros(3, 3, 3, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float64)
```

When I perform the calculation

```
temp= data1[:,0,0]+data2[:,0,0]
```

I would like to see the result in form of size ([3])tensor instead of ([3,1,1])

So considering the performance,

1. I should extract from the `data1, data2` or `temp`?
2. How to do this?

Comment: From your example `temp.shape` is actually `torch.Size([3])`

Comment: If you wanted the other way around, use slices: `data1[:, 0:1, 0:1]`

Comment: I think ```.squeeze()``` is a good choice as you mentioned before

Answer (score 1):

As [@paime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13636407/paime) said, you can use single element slices instead of single indexes:

```
>>> data1[:,:1,:1] + data2[:,:1,:1]
tensor([[[1.]],

        [[1.]],

        [[1.]]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

Alternatively, there are different ways of unsqueezing multiple dimensions at the same time:

- Using two [`torch.Tensor.unsqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)

  ```
  >>> temp.unsqueeze(-1).unsqueeze(-1)
  ```
- Reshaping the tensor with a view:

  ```
  >>> temp.view(*temp.shape, 1, 1)
  ```
- Or with fancy indexing:

  ```
  >>> temp[..., None, None]
  ```

Comment: The unpacking when reshaping with a view should be with a single star: `temp.view(*temp.shape, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Indeed thank you, that was a typo. fixed.